# Twilio Python Program Stuck (Undeclared Variables as Function Parameters)

Tags: python, syntax, parameters, global-variables, twilio

I have the following code, but it seems to get stuck in the Text function before the debug print statement. I have a feeling it has to do with how my function parameters are set up with variables, but I'm not sure what the correct way to do this is.

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

Initialize(debug=False):
    global Twilio
    Twilio = TwilioRestClient('***', '***')
    global Numbers
    Numbers = {'***':'+***', '***':'+***', '***':'+***'}
    if debug:
        print 'Intialize Debug Enabled'

def Text(message, recipient, debug=False):
    Twilio.messages.create(body=message, to=recipient, from_='+***')
    if debug:
        print 'Text Debug Enabled'

while True:
    Initialize(True)
    Text('***', Numbers['***'], True)
```

Comment: shouldn't `Initialize` start with `def` keyword ?

Comment: Yes, it should, and it does it my original code. I'll edit the post to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

client = None
Numbers = None

def Initialize(debug=False):
    global client
    client = TwilioRestClient('***', '***')
    global Numbers
    Numbers = {'***':'+***', '***':'+***', '***':'+***'}
    if debug:
        print 'Intialize Debug Enabled'

def Text(message, recipient, debug=False):
    client.messages.create(body=message, to=recipient, from_='+***')
    if debug:
        print 'Text Debug Enabled'

Initialize(True)

for k, v in Numbers.items():
    Text(k, v, True)
```